# msdata:PrimaryKey="true" and AllowDBNull="True"

Tags: c#, ado.net, xsd

Anyone any clues why these 2 don't work in combo?

I have taken an xsd generated from a DB that sports a primary key across several fields. one of those fields allows null so that field can contain null as long as the rest of the fields maintain the key.

Problem is when I describe this constraint in XSD the primarykey=true trumps allowdbnull and the 2 can't coexist.

I have a table of data that has been inserted using other means causing me no end of problem as I am merged 2 tables 1 of which has this xsd constraint.

Any clues?

Comment: What DB software or you using ? SQLServer does not allow any column that participates in a primary key to be nullible.

Comment: Can you post the declaration?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was sitting at home and this was doing my head in. After your comments I checked (sorry) and you are right a PK element can not have a null field even if it is still unique. I checked the DB and it WASN'T a PK but for some reason VS had put the msdata:primarykey=true on the unique constraint in the XSD.

Comment: Incidentally the HasErrors and RowError properties are god sends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find some info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8bhbatb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). From an XML Schema perspective, considering your scenario, I would use xs:unique instead, since that allows for null value scenarios; also xsd:unique constraints may be referenced in xsd:keyref, just like xsd:keys.